# Randomly getting "An operations error occurred in ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I have two application running on the same server, using the same forms based authentication:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://domain.example.name"/>
</connectionStrings>
...
<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyAdMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
...
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
...
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="28800"/>
</authentication>
...
```

Randomly 1 of the applications will start to trigger this error message:

[image]

Every time an attempt login to the application is done, the error message comes up.  The other application using the same authentication method continues to run fine.  When I reboot the system, both apps work fine.

I'm really at a loss as to why this happens in the first place, and how to troubleshoot it further.  Is there a way to fully 'inspect' the transaction when it attempts to authenticate on the LDAP server, and find any more information about why the attempt fails, and triggers the error message?

Any help is greatly appreciated, it happens randomly about once a month.

Comment: Still stumped on this.  It still comes up from time to time, it seems every time after a Windows Update.  Oddly even though the server probably restarts after the updates, restarting fixes this issue.  Something with the updates and the restarting is trigger it. Still searching.